# Apache SSL Proxy not redirects and not starts (although works without https)

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I'm trying to configure simple ssl reverse proxy on Apache 2.4.
But when I start server - it just doesn't work (getting 'Site can't be reached'), although if I change VirtualHost to remove ssl part - all works.

Here is config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443> 
  ServerName localhost

  SSLEngine On
  SSLProxyEngine On

  SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/ssl/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/ssl/server.key"

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

  LogLevel debug

</VirtualHost>
```

config test output:

```
>> httpd.exe -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS -D DUMP_MODULES
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  localhost (C:/Programs/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf:542)
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 win32_module (static)
 mpm_winnt_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 allowmethods_module (shared)
 asis_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 isapi_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 vhost_alias_module (shared)
```

Startup log output (debug level):

```
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:32.852330 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 19344:tid 156] AH01914: Configuring server localhost:443 for SSL protocol
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:32.852330 2019] [ssl:debug] [pid 19344:tid 156] ssl_engine_init.c(1758): AH10083: Init: (localhost:443) mod_md support is unavailable.
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:32.853327 2019] [ssl:debug] [pid 19344:tid 156] ssl_engine_init.c(488): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:32.853327 2019] [ssl:debug] [pid 19344:tid 156] ssl_util_ssl.c(476): AH02412: [localhost:443] Cert matches for name 'localhost' [subject: CN=localhost,O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd,ST=Some-State,C=AU / issuer: CN=localhost,O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd,ST=Some-State,C=AU / serial: FF13A83C528B363E / notbefore: Aug 12 19:12:23 2019 GMT / notafter: Aug 11 19:12:23 2020 GMT]
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:32.853327 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 19344:tid 156] AH02568: Certificate and private key localhost:443:0 configured from C:/Programs/Apache24/ssl/server.crt and C:/Programs/Apache24/ssl/server.key
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:33.701557 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 19344:tid 156] AH01914: Configuring server localhost:443 for SSL protocol
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:33.701557 2019] [ssl:debug] [pid 19344:tid 156] ssl_engine_init.c(1758): AH10083: Init: (localhost:443) mod_md support is unavailable.
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:33.701557 2019] [ssl:debug] [pid 19344:tid 156] ssl_engine_init.c(488): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:33.701557 2019] [ssl:debug] [pid 19344:tid 156] ssl_util_ssl.c(476): AH02412: [localhost:443] Cert matches for name 'localhost' [subject: CN=localhost,O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd,ST=Some-State,C=AU / issuer: CN=localhost,O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd,ST=Some-State,C=AU / serial: FF13A83C528B363E / notbefore: Aug 12 19:12:23 2019 GMT / notafter: Aug 11 19:12:23 2020 GMT]
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:33.701557 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 19344:tid 156] AH02568: Certificate and private key localhost:443:0 configured from C:/Programs/Apache24/ssl/server.crt and C:/Programs/Apache24/ssl/server.key
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:33.702557 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 19344:tid 156] AH00455: Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:33.702557 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 19344:tid 156] AH00456: Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: May 28 2019 17:12:51
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:33.702557 2019] [core:notice] [pid 19344:tid 156] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd.exe -d C:/Programs/Apache24'
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:33.703557 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 19344:tid 156] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 26392
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:34.795011 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 26392:tid 732] AH01914: Configuring server localhost:443 for SSL protocol
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:34.796011 2019] [ssl:debug] [pid 26392:tid 732] ssl_engine_init.c(1758): AH10083: Init: (localhost:443) mod_md support is unavailable.
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:34.796011 2019] [ssl:debug] [pid 26392:tid 732] ssl_engine_init.c(488): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:34.797026 2019] [ssl:debug] [pid 26392:tid 732] ssl_util_ssl.c(476): AH02412: [localhost:443] Cert matches for name 'localhost' [subject: CN=localhost,O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd,ST=Some-State,C=AU / issuer: CN=localhost,O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd,ST=Some-State,C=AU / serial: FF13A83C528B363E / notbefore: Aug 12 19:12:23 2019 GMT / notafter: Aug 11 19:12:23 2020 GMT]
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:34.797026 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 26392:tid 732] AH02568: Certificate and private key localhost:443:0 configured from C:/Programs/Apache24/ssl/server.crt and C:/Programs/Apache24/ssl/server.key
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:35.641038 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 26392:tid 732] AH01914: Configuring server localhost:443 for SSL protocol
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:35.641038 2019] [ssl:debug] [pid 26392:tid 732] ssl_engine_init.c(1758): AH10083: Init: (localhost:443) mod_md support is unavailable.
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:35.641038 2019] [ssl:debug] [pid 26392:tid 732] ssl_engine_init.c(488): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:35.641038 2019] [ssl:debug] [pid 26392:tid 732] ssl_util_ssl.c(476): AH02412: [localhost:443] Cert matches for name 'localhost' [subject: CN=localhost,O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd,ST=Some-State,C=AU / issuer: CN=localhost,O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd,ST=Some-State,C=AU / serial: FF13A83C528B363E / notbefore: Aug 12 19:12:23 2019 GMT / notafter: Aug 11 19:12:23 2020 GMT]
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:35.641038 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 26392:tid 732] AH02568: Certificate and private key localhost:443:0 configured from C:/Programs/Apache24/ssl/server.crt and C:/Programs/Apache24/ssl/server.key
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:35.642043 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 26392:tid 732] proxy_util.c(1932): AH00925: initializing worker http://localhost:8080/ shared
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:35.642043 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 26392:tid 732] proxy_util.c(1989): AH00927: initializing worker http://localhost:8080/ local
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:35.642043 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 26392:tid 732] proxy_util.c(2023): AH00930: initialized pool in child 26392 for (localhost) min=0 max=64 smax=64
[Mon Aug 12 22:14:35.642043 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 26392:tid 732] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```